# Where to report problems with Ask Ubuntu RSS feeds?

Tags: support, bug, rss

Ask Ubuntu's "recent questions" RSS at https://askubuntu.com/feeds has been hard down since April 3 21:26. The feed is visible using Firefox, but not when using an RSS app Liferea, or by using the RSS component in Thunderbird. Where can I report this problem so that it can get fixed?

Note: My previous post at [Ask Ubuntu "recent questions" RSS down since April 1st 2017 09:00](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16867/ask-ubuntu-recent-questions-rss-down-since-april-1st-2017-0900) showed problems going back to April 1st.

**Update**:

Effective April 7... the RSS feed is working again.

Comment: Unable to reproduce - RSS applications here are able to access the feed fine.  What RSS application are you using?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'down', please?

Comment: @ThomasWard   I'm using Liferea. The problem began April 1 when Liferea stopped getting new posts. It turns out that some kind of conversion from http to https is ongoing. So when I changed my feed to https, it started working again. However, since April 3 it's no longer getting any new posts. In both cases, going to the RSS source page in Firefox, I could see the new posts... but not via RSS. So I tried using the RSS component of Thunderbird, and it does the same thing.

Comment: @ThomasWard   Ubuntu 16.10. Liferea 1.10.19. Thunderbird 45.8.0.

Answer (score 2):

Bugs about the SE sites should be reported on meta (the specific site's meta, or the main [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) - [either will do fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89228/270345)), as a question tagged [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug). Usual time for a response/fix is [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/270345). As you have already done this, there's not much more to be done, except wait and/or look for workarounds.